# Simplifying atan(tan(a+b))

Tags: trigonometry, simplify, maxima, simplification

I wonder why this doesn't work as expected:

```
assume(x+y < %pi/2);
assume(x+y > -%pi/2);
atan(tan(x+y));
```

It reduces to:

```
atan(tan(x+y))
```

i.e. not at all. I would have expected it to reduce to:

```
x+y
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `triginverses`.

```
(%i9) atan (tan (x + y));
(%o9)                          atan(tan(y + x))
(%i10) %, triginverses=all;
(%o10)                               y + x
```